# Server Error: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, ssl, .net-4.5, cloudflare, windows-server-2012

I'm getting the error

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

on a request being made to an HTTPS endpoint on Cloudflare.

Code:

```
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    var wc = new WebClient();
    var json = wc.DownloadString("https://cloudflare.com");
    Console.Write(json);
```

This is a commonly asked question on Stack Overflow, where setting the ServicePoint to TLS1.2 fixes it. That fixes it for me locally. However whenever I promote the code to the Server, the error comes back (and I'm positive my code changes have been applied). If I remove the HTTPS and use HTTP it works fine.

After tons of searching I found this KB: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3109853 Which I installed on Server1, and it did not fix the problem.

Anyone know what else to try? There must be something about the Server environment that is causing this. It's up to date on .NET fixes/security updates.

```
[WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +823
   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +84

[HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.]
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +181
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +66
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +30
   TrackerBase.Controllers.<Verify>d__0.MoveNext() +535
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) +181
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) +66
   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) +30
   lambda_method(Closure , Task ) +40
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass3f.<BeginInvokeAsynchronousActionMethod>b__3e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +80
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +386
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +30
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +185
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +900
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +1299
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +42
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +38
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.OnAsyncHandlerCompletion(IAsyncResult ar) +18
```

Comment: Can you show us your code? you've shown us what the problem is, but not what you are doing or how you are trying to do it. We need to see enough to be able to reproduce the error ourselves.

Comment: @user1666620 Updated question with code. I was able to comment out the top line, drop it into dotnetfiddle to reproduce the error.  Uncomment the line, and then it works. But not on my server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no particular reason why that code should fail on Windows Server 2012; TLS is available and turned on by default (I tested your code sample on some fresh 2012 R2 boxes because I'm paranoid that way).

That means there is something about the configuration of your specific server that is stopping the connection from using TLS 1.2. Check the following things:

- In the registry, check `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols` . Are any protocols disabled (or even mentioned) outside SSL 2.0 ?
- In the event log on the server, are there any `Schannel` events after a failed connection event?
- On the server, open https://cloudfare.com using your browser. Right click, properties (assuming IE), does it say `TLS 1.2, AES with 128 bit encryption (High)`? If not, the browser decided to use a different protocol because TLS 1.2 was somehow not available on the client system.

Comment: TLS 1,1.1,1.2 are the only protocols enabled. I tried to open the site in IE 11 and it says `Turn on TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1, and TLS 1.2 in Advanced settings `  I checked advanced settings, they are all enabled.  So something is definitely up.  Chrome works though.  I googled for a bit on the IE error and not coming up with much.

Comment: I checked my other windows servers, they work fine. So it's not an IE11 issue.

Comment: I figured it out.  Apparently when poodle dropped, I used a tool to disable insecure protocols (ssl 3) and part of those best practices had me disabling some ciphers too.  My other server had not been updated yet. So apparently best practices aren't always best practices.

Comment: the tool is called "IIS crypto" for any other poor souls who used it.  I'm going to mark this answer as accepted because directing me to use IE was what got me on the right track. Chrome apparently is smart enough to use secure ciphers.

Comment: Well done figuring things out! I suspect you might have misinterpreted the protocol settings in the registry, and TLS 1/1.1/1.2 where actually *disabled* in the registry (if they are enabled, there usually are no related keys present at all). IE, as well as any .NET application using the underlying internet layer, respects those registry settings. Chrome et al have their own internet layer and ignore them.

Comment: I've the same problem accessing https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts.xml on a Windows 2012 server... I'm using .NET V4.8, and it works on my dev machine (Windows 10). In IIS Crypto all protocols and ciphers are checked... What else could I do ?